# JPA - Is there a mechanism for mapping a column value to a value object?

Tags: java, jpa

Is there a JPA mechanism to automatically convert column values like `String`, `Integer`, etc to a Value Object like my `MyDate`?

In my case for every field which represents a MyDate there's code in the getter an setter to convert from `Integer` to `MyDate` and visa versa. This code duplication increases out of proportion.

The following looks like I'm looking for. MyDate is not an Entity but a Value Object.

```
@Column (name = "d_end")
private MyDate dEnd;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of JPA's @Embeddable and @Embedded:

try creating your `MyDate` class with annotation: `@Embeddable`, also define db columns in `MyDate`.

then in your entity:

```
@Embedded
private MyDate dEnd;
```

### EDIT

I wanted to paste a meaningful example, after short google, I found this link, read it, it explains how to use them in details (with examples):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables

Comment: Thank you for taking time answering my question.
But what in case I would like to use MyDate for all kinds of MyDate culumns with diffent names in all kinds of entities?

Comment: Should have read on first. Found something that might be a solution: [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Sharing)

Comment: @Barthelomeus then I think it would be the right case to use `@Type` and `@TypeDef`  see here for example, exactly what you are looking for: http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types

Comment: This is the thing I was looking for. Unfortunately I use EclipseLink. Equivalent annotation in EclipseLink, I believe, is `@Converter`. The amount of documentation on this is not overwhelming. So, I've to find out if this could solve my problem.